# Creating a Play/Pause button for AVPlayer in another View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am creating a Play/Pause button for an AVPlayer, but the actual player is in a `UIView` and the button is in the `UIViewController` where I am creating an instance of the player. The video plays if I simply put `[self.player play];` in the code for the player, but when I try to control playing and pausing from the button it doesn't.

Here is the code:

```
-(IBAction)playPauseButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
   PlayerView *player = [[PlayerView alloc] init];

   if (self.playing == YES)
  {
    [player.player pause];
    self.playing = NO;
    NSLog(@"Pause");
  }
  else
  {
   [player.player play];
    NSLog(@"Play");
    self.playing = YES;
  }

//    UIButton *theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
//    
//    self.playing = !self.playing;
//    [theButton setImage:self.playing ? @"pauseImage.png":@"playImage.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to study well about Object Oriented Concepts and Object communication.

You are creating the PlayerView class object inside your `playPauseButtonClicked` again.

Instead, you have to pass the existing `PlayerView` object into the class that contains `playPauseButtonClicked` method.

**Example:**

***Class A:***

```
ClassB *classB = [[ClassB alloc] init];
classB.player = self.player;
```

***Class B:***

**.h file**

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) PlayerView *player;
```

**.m file**

```
-(IBAction)playPauseButtonClicked:(id)sender { 

 if (self.player.playing == YES)
 {
    [self.player pause];
    self.player.playing = NO;
    NSLog(@"Pause");
 }
 else
 {
   [self.player play];
    NSLog(@"Play");
    self.player.playing = YES;
 }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

First You pass your PlayerView Object to next View Controller

And In FirstViewController.h and SecondViewController.h file declare object of PlayerView

Such As

**@property (nonatomic,retain) PlayerView *player;**

And when navigate from first view controller to second view controller inlude this code:

**SecondViewController *obj = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
  obj.player = self.player ;**

Now In **-(IBAction)playPauseButtonClicked:(id)sender** Method of second view controller

**Remove The Line from Code  :** PlayerView *player = [[PlayerView alloc] init];

because a above line create new object of Player View instead of object of previous view controller AVPlayer Object write this updated method

```
-(IBAction)playPauseButtonClicked:(id)sender { 

    if (self.playing == YES)
    {
        [player.player pause];
        self.playing = NO;
        NSLog(@"Pause");
    }
    else
    {
        [player.player play];
        NSLog(@"Play");
        self.playing = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have made the player in a UIView, and then create an instance of it in my viewController. I am trying to make the player created in the view play and pause